# I removed a spark plug from my “98” Lincoln to replace it, when I went to put the new one in it wouldn’t set down in and tighten. Will canned air work

Tags: sparkplugs, spark

I removed a spark plug from my “98” Lincoln to replace it, when I went to put the new one in it wouldn’t tighten. Can I use canned air without a spark plug in the well?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you think the canned air is going to do for you? Are you sure you have the correct replacement spark plug? Can you tell if there are any physical differences between the new and old sparkplug? Can you post an image of both of them showing the threaded areas next to each other?

Comment: Was the old plug damaged? Was it very difficult to remove? Were the threads damged during removal or did someone install the old plug badly? Does the old plug still go back in correctly?

Comment: Why would you change one plug ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use canned air, since you'll likely blow debris into the spark plug hole and down into the cylinder.  Twist [a narrow bristle brush](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094HM39CX) soaked with Seafoam into the spark plug threads, then pull the brush straight out.  Clean the brush and repeat until the there is no more dirt.  Allow the threads to soak with Seafoam overnight, then brush more vigorously again in the morning.

I've actually used this method with the exact brush set I linked to on Amazon.  In my case, the car was even older (a 1994 Taurus).  The spark plug threads were heavily carbonized and I even removed a few slivers of metal.  The new plugs glided in like a brand new car.  It's been running fine for about 3,000 miles since then.  Note that you could probably substitute WD-40 for the Seafoam with good results.